# Change a LVM/extended to an ext4

Tags: storage, partition

There seemed to be some miscommunication or confusion upon the installation of solusvm for my machine.
From what I understand, I will not need an LVM for OpenVZ-based installations. So far, that's been true. I have a 77G partition that is being used and mounted to /

The drive in its entirety is 240G. There is an LVM/extended that is taking up 140G of space, with nothing on it. `pvscan` shows that it is empty, `df -h` does not show it at all, and further commands have similar outcomes.

I am looking for a way to wipe the LVM drive/partition which in this case is /dev/sda5. The "extended" is /dev/sda4

Here is the output of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29185 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d3908

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       10263    81920000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           10263       10785     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4           10785       29186   147803136    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           10785       29186   147802112   8e  Linux LVM
```

I wish to change sda4/5 and create a single drive as an ext4 partition. I will then mount that sda within the system to some directory as a 140G partition.

I feel that I have misinterpreted something here though, so please let me know if something is completely wrong or if you need further information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is nothing located on `/dev/sda5`, what you need to do is to change the partition type of the partition, create a ext4 filesystem on it and then mount it.

First of all, you may want to run `blkid /dev/sda5` to verify that there isn't anything there. If it identifies something and you want to overwrite it, you can do that using `wipefs --all /dev/sda5`.

You can then use the `t` command in `fdisk` to change the partition type. (Strictly speaking, this step isn't really necessary, but it helps to keep the partition table clean.) Here you want to change the partition type to `83`, which is the same as your other file systems:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
[...]
Command (m for help): t
Partition number (1,2,5, default 5): 5
Hex code (type L to list all codes): 83

Changed type of partition 'Linux LVM' to 'Linux'.
```

Save the changes using the `w` command.

You can then create a new file system on it using `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda5`.

Then you probably want to add an entry for it in `/etc/fstab`. E.g. something like:

```
/dev/sda5  /targetdir  ext4  defaults  0  2
```

And then finally mount it: `mount /targetdir`